# Arduino and a Web Server JAVA online, how makes a communication?

Tags: java, web-services, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I was trying make the communication between a page hosted in Web Server JAVA and the arduino , but i don't got successes . I have a page JSP hosted in Web Server JAVA and i want use there to control the arduino , sending and getting data : temperatura , state of lamp , control of my gate and others .. But , how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

your question is too broad. There are many ways of doing this. Primarly, you should understand how will you connect the computer running the web server to the arduino. Is it physically connected to it via a serial port, ethernet or wirelessly? does the arduino have an ethernet or wifi shield? bluetooth? usb?

With that solved, it should be somewhat easy to make your JSP delegate on a Servlet which, in turn, would interact with the arduino depending on the form of connection mentioned before.

But, in general, this has little to do with web/JSP and a lot to do with arduino communication. Hope it helps. If you provide further details I can refine my answer.

Comment: The arduino have a Ethernet Shield  and JSP is hosted on a web hosting server .. 
Thank you for help

Comment: But I  have no idea what the code to make communication between a page JSP that is in a Web Hosting Server and my arduino that is in my house . Where do I start ?